# eth1 disappear after use new kernel 5.6.0 | uSID | Centos

Tags: networking, centos, kernel

In order to test SRv6 uSID in Linux, I compiled the new kernel 5.6.0 that in following Github:
https://github.com/netgroup/srv6-usid-linux-kernel.git

After compiled and reboot, my 2nd network adapter port(eth1) disappeared, two network adapter ports should the same type, and only eth0 was renamed to ens3, as follow:

```
[root@frank cisco]# uname -a
Linux frank 5.6.0+ #3 SMP Tue Jun 30 17:32:20 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@frank cisco]# dmesg |grep eth
[    2.311925] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 5e:00:00:00:00:00
[    2.314897] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.770167] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth1: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) fa:16:3e:38:fd:91
[    2.773194] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    5.352825] e1000 0000:00:03.0 ens3: renamed from eth0
[root@frank cisco]# 
[root@frank cisco]# lshw -class network -businfo
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
pci@0000:00:03.0  ens3        network        82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
pci@0000:00:04.0              network        82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Follow is dmesg for two ports:

```
[root@frank cisco]# dmesg |grep 00:03.0
[    0.700489] pci 0000:00:03.0: [8086:100e] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.702057] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfeb80000-0xfeb9ffff]
[    0.703921] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x14: [io  0xc000-0xc03f]
[    0.707532] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfeb00000-0xfeb3ffff pref]
[    2.311925] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 5e:00:00:00:00:00
[    2.314897] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    5.352825] e1000 0000:00:03.0 ens3: renamed from eth0
[root@frank cisco]# 
[root@frank cisco]# dmesg |grep 00:04.0
[    0.708456] pci 0000:00:04.0: [8086:100e] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.710057] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfeba0000-0xfebbffff]
[    0.711846] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 0x14: [io  0xc040-0xc07f]
[    0.715515] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfeb40000-0xfeb7ffff pref]
[    2.770167] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth1: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) fa:16:3e:38:fd:91
[    2.773194] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
```

Follow lshw cmd
"driver=uio_pci_generic"

```
[root@frank v2.81]#  lshw -c network
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: ens3
       version: 03
       serial: 5e:00:00:00:00:00
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=172.16.1.140 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:10 memory:feb80000-feb9ffff ioport:c000(size=64) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master rom
       configuration: driver=uio_pci_generic latency=0 <<<
       resources: irq:11 memory:feba0000-febbffff ioport:c040(size=64) memory:feb40000-feb7ffff
```

And found the port bound by dpdk, but I didn't set any bound config...

```
[root@frank v2.81]# ./dpdk_setup_ports.py -s

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:00:04.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000,igb_uio,vfio-pci   <<<

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller' if=ens3 drv=e1000 unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic 

Other network devices
=====================
<none>
```

Does anyone know what is going on...and how to solve this problem...?

Thanks a lot!
Frank

Answer (score 0):

After discussed with colleagues, the issue should be followed by this link:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/uio-howto.html

And as above guide, I can workaround the issue, but issue appear again after reboot...

```
[root@frank v2.81]# ls -l /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:04.0/driver
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jun 30 17:59 /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:04.0/driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic
[root@frank v2.81]# echo -n 0000:00:04.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/unbind
[root@frank v2.81]# echo -n 0000:00:04.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/e1000/bind
[79965.358393] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) fa:16:3e:38:fd:91
[79965.360499] e1000 0000:00:04.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[root@frank v2.81]# ls -l /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:04.0/driver
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jul  1 16:12 /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:04.0/driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/e1000
[root@frank cisco]# ifconfig eth0 up
[  221.792886] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[  221.796553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[root@frank cisco]# lshw -c network
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: ens3
       version: 03
       serial: 5e:00:00:00:00:00
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=172.16.1.140 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:11 memory:feb80000-feb9ffff ioport:c000(size=64) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: fa:16:3e:38:fd:91
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:11 memory:feba0000-febbffff ioport:c040(size=64) memory:feb40000-feb7ffff
```